# Pythonic way to get the single element of a 1-sized list

Tags: python

What's the most pythonic way to take the single item of a 1-sized list in python?

I usually go for

```
item = singlet_list[0]
```

This would fail for an empty list, but I would like a way to make it fail even if the list is longer, something like:

```
assert(len(singlet_list) == 1)
item = singlet_list[0]
```

but I find this ugly. Is there anything better?

Comment: what happens if the list is empty or has more than one item?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham for my use case I'd like it to fail loudly in the case this happens. My point here was that, if the list is longer, the first option does something and works (implicitly makes a choice selecting the first in the sequence). The second snippet, instead, fails loudly for both too long and too short inputs, but it is on 2 lines and somewhat brakes the flow of the code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This [blog post](http://blog.ram.rachum.com/post/1198230058/python-idiom-for-taking-the-single-item-from-a-list) suggests an elegant solution I fell in love with:

```
(item,) = singlet_list
```

I find it much more readable, and plus it works with any iterable, even if it is not indexable.

EDIT: Let me dig a little more

This construct is called [sequence unpacking](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) or [multiple assignment](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming) throughout the python documentation, but here I'm using a 1-sized tuple on the left of the assignment.

This has actually a behaviour that is similar to the 2-lines in the initial question: if the list/iterable `singlet_list` is of length 1, it will assign its only element to `item`. Otherways, it will fail with an appropriate `ValueError` (rather than an `AssertionError` as in the question's 2-liner):

```
>>> (item,) = [1]
>>> item
1
>>> (item,) = [1, 2]
ValueError: too many values to unpack
>>> (item,) = []
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

As pointed out in the blog post, this has some advantages:

- This will *not* to fail silently, as required by the original question.
- It is much more readable than the `[0]` indexing, and it doesn't pass unobserved even in complex statements.
- It works for any [iterable](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterable) object.
- (Of course) it uses only one line, with respect to explicitly using `assert`

Comment: This method will still fail for empty lists. `ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack`

Comment: By the way, I was amazed by this solution, but I'll wait some time before accepting it, in case someone comes up with something even better

Comment: @Cyber Which is not a problem at all. When the list is empty, there isn't a value to extract.

Comment: @Davide I edited it with a way to avoid the ValueError if the list is empty.

Comment: @Cyber this was actually the point: don't fail silently if anything goes wrong and the list/sequence has more than 1 value.

Answer (score 3):

You could use an inline `if...else` and define a default value like this:

If `singlet_list` contains one or more values:

```
singlet_list = [2]
item = singlet_list[0] if singlet_list else False
print item
```

output:

```
2
```

If `singlet_list` is empty:

```
singlet_list = []
item = singlet_list[0] if singlet_list else False
print item
```

output:

```
False
```

This uses the fact that an empty list evaluates to `False`.

---

Similarly, if you would like a default value to be assigned if the list doesn't contain exactly one element, you could check the length:

```
item = singlet_list[0] if len(singlet_list) == 1 else False
```